# Create a Column to flag transactions that include a product

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have loaded 2 tables into the PowerBI data model:

**TransactionLine Table**: Unique Identifier is TransactionID + ProductID   *(see snapshot below)*

[image]

**Product Table**: Unique Identifier is ProductID. That table also includes a ProductCategory field

[image]

So what I am trying to do is create a flag on the first table (**TransactionLine Table**) that will say if that TransactionID includes a product from Category A. To be more specific if even 1 line of a transactionID includes a product from that category, I want all lines for that transactionID to be flagged the same. So that flag column will look like the below

[image]

Comment: Can you produce a sample data set and a desired output derived from the former?

Comment: Maybe a good idea to also include your other table? Did you create also a relation for them?

Comment: Hello. Thnx for getting back to me. I have included the snapshot of both tables and of what the flag would look like. The tables are linked with a relation with the field "ProductID"